# react-calendar Option to set calendar month index start at 1

Tags: reactjs

Is there a property to change to months index to start at 1 instead of zero, ie march = 3 but the output on the calendar is april, I can manually do this but its very hacky

Anyone know if there a property I can set on this library react-calendar
[The library](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-calendar/)

Comment: Why not only uses `index+1` ? In Programming, all starts in 0 to length-1

Comment: My point is I will be storing 3 on the server but javascript datepickers start at zero, I don't want to hack the response ie 3-1 is 2, i will be sending 3 back to server

Comment: I want to avoid hacking my code for every date

Answer (score 0):

you need to do few things.
1- set Min and max date value

const startDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), 1)

const endDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), 31)

then you need to specify those values within the calendar

```
<Calendar
                    data-name="yourselectionName"
                    data-value={hooksVariable}
                    onChange={hooksUpdateMethod}
                    value={currentDate}
                    minDate={startDate}
                    maxDate={endDate}
                    name={name}
  />
```

by then only dates in range will be selectable but you still need to hide date that are not within range using css by this:

```
.react-calendar__month-view__days__day--neighboringMonth {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Important note: doing it that way will not allow you to navigate between different months, if you want to hide the unselectable inputs and be able to navigate to other months. just use the css line it will do it without any complications. Hope it helps